# How to save an image in local storage using angular reactive form?

Tags: angular, typescript, image, forms, angular-reactive-forms

I am building an angular project where I want to upload an image using angular reactive form and then save that image in localstorage.

Following is the code snippet of "edit.component.html".

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="save()">
<label class="head1">Photo</label> <br>
<input type="file" formControlName="Photo">
<button [disabled]="form.invalid">Save</button>
</form>
```

Following is the code snippet of "edit.component.ts".

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators, FormArray} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-edit',
  templateUrl: './edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./edit.component.css']
})
export class EditComponent {
form=new FormGroup({
    Photo:new FormControl(null,Validators.required),
});
save(){
    var profile;

    if(localStorage.getItem("profile")==null){
      profile={};
    }
    else{
      profile=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")!);
    }
}
}
```

When I added this line `const photo = this.form.get('Photo') as File;` in the save() function of ts file, I got the error

```
Conversion of type 'AbstractControl<null, null> | null' to type 'File' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.
  Type 'AbstractControl<null, null>' is missing the following properties from type 'File': lastModified, name, webkitRelativePath, size, and 6 more.ts(2352)
```

Now please help me by modifying or adding some code to save the image in localstorage and also display that image by getting from localstorage in the html page.

Answer (score 1):

You could convert image into string with `FileReader`, because local storage deals with strings, and then save it.

And then, you could read it from local storage and convert back to file with `File`, and add it to the form.

You can setup file field change listener, which will get the file, assign it to the form, and save it.

Here's demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2f5y34?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

You can modify it according to your needs.

Key methods:

file handler:

```
  <input
    type="file"
    formControlName="Photo"
    (change)="handleFileInput($event)"
  />
```

```
  handleFileInput(event: Event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;

    const files = target.files as FileList;

    const file = files[0];

    this.form.value.Photo = file;

    this.saveFile(file);
  }
```

save file:

```
  saveFile(file: File) {
    const reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = () => {
      console.log(reader.result);

      this.preview = reader.result as string;

      localStorage.setItem('profile', reader.result as string);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
```

read file:

```
 readFile() {
    const profile = localStorage.getItem('profile');

    console.log('reading ls image: ', profile);

    if (profile) {
      this.preview = profile;

      const contentType = profile.split(';')[0].replace('data:', '');

      const file = new File([profile], 'profile.jpeg', {
        type: contentType,
      });

      this.form.value.Photo = file;
    } else {
      this.preview = '';
    }
  }
```